# Not able to attach Role via AWS Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cloud9

I am new to Cloud9 and following [this URL](https://www.eksworkshop.com/advanced/420_kubeflow/) to setup Kubeflow in AWS.

Unfortunately, I am not able to attach the role to the user as mentioned in [this URL](https://www.eksworkshop.com/020_prerequisites/ec2instance/).

Could anyone please suggest what could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

While [the link](https://www.eksworkshop.com/020_prerequisites/ec2instance/) did not work for me here, below suggestion provided by AWS support worked for me.

Please navigate to Preferences on the menu bar in the AWS Cloud9 IDE.
- On the Preferences tab, in the navigation pane, choose AWS Settings-->Credentials.
- Use AWS managed temporary credentials to turn AWS managed temporary credentials on or off.